# camel-cxfrs with custom http headers

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I have a route that defines a CXFRS endpoint.  I need to retrieve custom HTTP header values from the inbound request...

```
from(CXF_RS_ENDPOINT_URI)
      .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        Message inMessage = exchange.getIn();    
                        System.out.println("headers->" + inMessage.getHeaders());
                        ...
```

here is my unit test code to simulate a client request...

```
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9000/rest/customerservice/customers/126");
    get.addHeader("myHeader", "1234");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
```

The problem is that the custom header "myHeader" is unavailable from my route.  Is there another way to get to it?

From looking at the camel-cxf source code, I can see that the default header strategy/binding logic only sets up predefined HTTP headers.  Is there a reason why other headers aren't passed through as well?

Either way, what is the best approach to override this behavior?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigating, this was found to be a bug in CAMEL-CXF.  It has been fixed to support custom headers in the Camel trunk (slated for 2.5 release)...